# Does Renderer3 will be backwards compatible with Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular-renderer2

Does somebody knows, if Renderer3 in Angular6 will be backwards compatible with Angular5? In our library, we use Renderer2, and we wonder whether the Renderer3 will be backward compatible with Angular 5.

Comment: So Renderer3 is Ivy? i.e. not yet released and not supported yet

Comment: Renderer 3 is not Ivy Renderer. Ivy was released in Angular 6.

Comment: Ok now I’m more confused. So what is renderer3 and why does Pierre’s link refer to ivy. Also ivy isn’t really released yet - last time I looked I think there were 1000 open issues. All I wanted to do was add a css class to my body tag lol and I got curious. lol :)

Comment: Ivy Renderer is Renderer 3 according to https://theinfogrid.com/uncategorized/state-of-angular-january-2018/ and https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/interfaces/renderer.ts

Answer (score 5):

According to the [issue card](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706) it's supposed to be backwards compatible. But considering how much has changed already, [read here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706), it's hard to believe it's going to be compatible. Either way, it's too early to say